# How do I set the accessible text for TreeView items when using HierarchicalDataTemplates and multiple item types?

Tags: wpf, accessibility

I have an application with a `TreeView` control that is built using a set of data types representing different levels in the hierarchy and an accompanying set of `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s.  What I want to do now is set appropriate `AutomationProperties.Name` values on the tree items.

Normally, I would use `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` to bind the accessible name, but this is rather limited, as it requires I use a binding path that works for all types.

In this case, however, I would much rather be able to control the accessible name independently for each type.  For example, it may be useful to include `Id` in some layers, but not in others.

I could probably live with using the displayed text, but while I can easily use a `RelativeSource` binding in `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` to get at the `TreeViewItem`, the `Path` needed to ultimately reach the `TextBlock.Text` value in the templated item from there eludes me.

I have also tried using `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle`, but that only applies to child items.  Even further, when I tried to define it on each template, only `BazItem`s were properly set, even though I would have expected `BarItem`s to work as well.

I put together a minimal example to illustrate the issue.  The item types are as follows:

```
public sealed class BazItem
{
    public BazItem(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

public sealed class BarItem
{
    public BarItem(int id, string display)
    {
        Id = id;
        Display = display ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(display));
        Bazs = new ObservableCollection<BazItem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Display { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<BazItem> Bazs { get; }
}

public sealed class FooItem
{
    public FooItem(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        Bars = new ObservableCollection<BarItem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public ObservableCollection<BarItem> Bars { get; }
}
```

The corresponding templates are as follows:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BazItem}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='baz: {0}'}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BarItem}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Bazs}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Display, StringFormat='bar: {0}'}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FooItem}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Bars}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='foo: {0}'}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Finally, the tree view in the view is as follows:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}"/>
```

where Foos is an `ObservableCollection<FooItem>` property on the underlying view.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with for now (pending a better answer) is to change the `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` to use a value converter against the tree item object rather than a property on the object:

TreeView element:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=View, Path=Foos}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AccessibleConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string), ParameterType = typeof(Type))]
public sealed class AccessibleTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case FooItem foo:
                return $"foo: {foo.Name}";
            case BarItem bar:
                return $"bar: {bar.Display}";
            case BazItem baz:
                return $"baz: {baz.Name}";
            default:
                return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This works, but it's less-than-ideal for several reasons:

1. it duplicates the format strings (though I could pull them out into a shared resource location)
2. the value converter has to first convert `object` to the appropriate type before it can come up with the appropriate string format
3. adding a new tree item type requires I touch both the templates as well as the value converter

Answer (score 0):

I came along the same issue and the way I solved it was by overriding the ToString() method of the class of the object i was binding the TreeViewItem.

For example, in your case the type of item you bind to TreeViewItem is of type BazItem, go to BazItem class and:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    // This is what the Windows Narrator will use now
    return "Name of Baz Item";
}
```